The Kohler instruction manual says 3/32" hex but it seems small and is almost stripping the screw what do i do?
I'm trying to replace a kohler K-TS14423-4 cartridge and I'm nearly stripping the screw to get the cover off because the 3/32" hex key they said to use is not working. It seems small. What am I supposed to do?

Make sure the screw and/or the hex key are not rounded. If still too small, try the next larger size, or might try metric sizes for the right fit.   Rounded screws get nasty to remove(drilling/grinding).

I don't have a Kohler, but I had to rummage up a 7/64" hex key to get my shower handle off. That's the next size up and a bit challenging to locate at the local level.

Thanks I will try the next size up and see if it works.

Try the metric equivalent.
